# block comment with labels/counters preserved

Tags: equations, comments

I am trying to produce two documents from the same latex source. One is a set of notes (e.g. a book) and the other is a set of slides to use in lectures. I would like to exclude some of the content in the slide that appear in the book.

Currently I am using the comment package with redefinition of my own commands such as `\slidesonly{Omitted text.}` . It works well, except that I would like the equation number and figure numbers to be the same in each document (even if some equations of figures have been excluded in the slides). But the comment package does not update the equation and figure counters.

Does anyone know of a package that will do this?

Here is a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}

Here is the first equation
\begin{equation}\label{eq:first}
a = b
\end{equation}

Here is the second equation, commented out.
\begin{comment}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:second}
a = b
\end{equation}
\end{comment}


Here is the third equation. 
\begin{equation}\label{eq:thrid}
e = f
\end{equation}
This is equation (\ref{eq:thrid}). It should be equation (3). 
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There may be an easy way to do this using the [comment](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comments) package but I don't know how it works (in particular, it was not clear to me from the manual how to enable and disable comments), so I give another approach.

Using the [environ](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ) package, and a simple switch, is it easy to do want you want. First, define a new if-statement with

```
\newif\ifIncludeComments
```

If you put `\IncludeCommentsfalse` then the contents of the comments environments will be ignored and if you use `\IncludeCommentstrue` then the comments will be printed. To define a comment environment we use `\NewEnviron` from the [environ](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ) package. This command defines an environment that slurps the contents of the environment into a `\BODY` macro, which we can then process. Using this we can define the `comment` environment to be:

```
\NewEnviron{comment}{\ifIncludeComments\BODY\fi}
```

That is, the `comment` environment will print its contents when we are including comments and otherwise it will ignore them. If we have an equation inside a `comment` environment then we should completely ignore the contents *but* in order to preserve the equation numbers we need to increment the `equation` counter. We can do this using:

```
\NewEnviron{cequation}{%
    \ifIncludeComments\equation\BODY\endequation% add equation
    \else\refstepcounter{equation}% step counter
    \fi%
}
```

This defines a new environment `cequation` that puts its contents inside an `equation` environment if we are printing comments and otherwise it just adds `1` to the equation counter. You could do the same with the `figure` environment except that you would use `\refstepcounter{figure}`.

Putting this all together, your MWE becomes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\newif\ifIncludeComments

\IncludeCommentsfalse
%\IncludeCommentstrue

\NewEnviron{comment}{\ifIncludeComments\BODY\fi}
\NewEnviron{cequation}{% comment for equations
    \ifIncludeComments\equation\BODY\endequation%
    \else\refstepcounter{equation}%
    \fi%
}
\NewEnviron{cfigure}{% comment for figures
    \ifIncludeComments\figure\BODY\endfigure%
    \else\refstepcounter{figure}%
    \fi%
}

\begin{document}
  Here is the first equation
  \begin{equation}\label{eq:first}
  a = b
  \end{equation}

  Here is the second equation, commented out.
  \begin{cequation}\label{eq:second}
  a = b
  \end{cequation}

  Here is the third equation.
  \begin{equation}\label{eq:third}
  e = f
  \end{equation}
  This is equation (\ref{eq:third}). It should be equation (3).
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `lrbox`. The material of the `lrbox` is not ignored. It is still set but not into the output but into a box register. So all counter changes are still there. You need an additional `minipage` inside the `lrbox`, because you want so have vertical material (and a `lrbox` is primary a horizontal box like `\mbox`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox\commentbox
\newenvironment{comment}{%
  \begin{lrbox}{\commentbox}\minipage{\linewidth}
}{%
  \endminipage
  \end{lrbox}%
}

\begin{document}

Here is the first equation
\begin{equation}\label{eq:first}
a = b
\end{equation}

Here is the second equation, commented out.
\begin{comment}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:second}
a = b
\end{equation}
\end{comment}


Here is the third equation. 
\begin{equation}\label{eq:thrid}
e = f
\end{equation}
This is equation (\ref{eq:thrid}). It should be equation (3). 
\end{document}
```

[image]

**But:** Labels corresponding with the counters inside the `comment` are not there, because labels are written/generated while the output of material and the `comment` environment does not output the `lrbox`.